# Can a beam of light, coherent or otherwise, conduct electricity, as does flame

Tags: visible-light, electricity

Can a beam of light,  coherent or otherwise,  conduct electricity.

Comment: Outline of an answer: start with [this argument that it is fields, not charges, which carry energy in an any electric circuit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/301027/44126). Transition to a discussion of how transmission-line issues (like signals in very long cables) have more to do with the behavior of the fields in the cable than the charges in the conductor. Point out that transmission lines for higher frequencies ("rf") are really "waveguides." Conclude by arguing that optical transmission *is* electromagnetic energy conduction, at petahertz frequencies. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Rob. Agreed that there is obviously em energy transfer in a beam of photons. If the beam is coherent,  it's frequency,  assuming it applies to all photons in the beam , could function as a waveguide for electrons "fired" along with the beam. Given a properly equipped laboratory,  this would be an excellent area of experimental investigation. Simple benchtop setups could explore sources and methods,  while obtaining critical measurement and conceptual design , should it be shown to be affirmative. (can a beam of light..... )Would be easy peasy lemon squeezee l